# There's no [us] in [usa]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags about questions pertaining specifically to the United States: [us](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) and [usa](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa). The latter is more popular (53 vs. 13 questions) and has a guidance excerpt; can the former be synonymized into it?

Comment: Ironically, adding "of America" to "United States" does not fully disambiguate it :). It appears there are United States's just north of the Yucatan Peninsula!  "The state formerly known as the British colonies in America" also does not suffice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good suggestion, consider it done, because it is.